# Using oil for shabbos lights as a segulah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, segulah

Is there a source for a segulah I heard, that if you light oil for shabbos candles, it is a segulah for having twins?

Comment: It's a halachic nice-to-have; I'd hope that would be good enough without the whole "segulah" business.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kaf HaChayim (264:38)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.264.38.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) mentions that using oil for your Shabbos candles, assures that you will have children learned (well) in Torah. Why? The Kaf HaChayim  says that [oil is compared to Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ki_Tavo.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and uses this idea to say this.

> לח) שם. שמן זית מצוה וכו'  ובמקום שמצוי שמן זית צריך ליזהר בו דהרגיל בנר הויין לו בנים רבנן ולכן צריך ליזהר בשמן זית כדי לזכות לבנים המאירים בתורה שנמשלה לשמן זית. מחב"ר או' ב' ועיין לעיל סי' רס"ג או' א'

The Midrash connects oil to Torah:

> And the Torah is compared to oil. Just like oil brings light to the whole world, so too is the Torah light to the world. [(Midrash Tanchuma, Ki Savo 3:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ki_Tavo.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

The Chida says similair. Lightning Shabbos candles with oil assures having children that are well-learned in Torah, since there is the concept that oil is compared to Torah (Machzik B’racha simon 264:2). See [this article](https://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos4_18.htm#_ftn3) by Rabbi Dovid
Ostroff.

** This is not specifically about segulah for having twins, but the concept is the same.